# what is the best way to check if the text of an element contains a predefined text

Tags: java, validation, selenium, assert, verify

I am composing an email and sending it to myself. I want to verify the title and the body has the same text I gave 
(note: the body might contain extra text like the signature added to it)
What is the best way in `selenium` to verify if the body contains the text I have sent? 
For eg:- I have sent text `"hello"` into my body, but after sending it now has `"hello    sent fromxxx"`
 Using `Java`. Looking for `selenese` commands that can verify this.e

Can someone please suggest

I am using something like this

```
 String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
 Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", bodyText.contains(text));
```

Comment: If you use web-browser (e.g. `Firefox`, `Chrome`...) to check your mail, you should define `HTML` of target element that you need to verify, if you use email client (like `MS Outlook`) you cannot use `selenium` for this purpose

Comment: I am using a web browser. Can you provide the syntax if possible

Comment: `selenium` works with programming language. Have you tried it? Which language you use? To handle elements you should get `HTML` source. You can get it with `F12` or by clicking mouse right-button on element and choosing something like `Explore element` or `Get element source`...

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Using JAVA. I am looking for selenium code that validates using contains or anything similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code

```
bodyText.contains(text);
```

will by itself return a boolean value that is True or False and the AssertTrue's output will be displayed in your console if the boolean value is false.